# How does Spring @profile work with inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, dependency-injection

Currently in a project, I have parent abstract classes called page object classes which are subclassed typically by 2 or 3 child classes, each being used based on a specific configuration (For example: platform as Android, IOS, Web).

```
@Component
public abstract class MePage {}


@Profile("android")
@Component
public class AndroidMePage extends MePage {}


@Profile("ios")
@Component
public class IOSMePage extends MePage {}
```

Whenever an instance of one of the subclasses is needed, it's retrieved using

```
@Autowired
MePage mePage;
```

**Question**
How does Spring work in such cases where subclasses are annotated with `@profile` and the parent class is an abstract class and also a component?

Does Spring automatically assign instance of one of the subclasses to the `@Autowired` abstract class variable based on the profile configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have `@Component` on top of an abstract class, since abstract classes are not meant to be instantiated (not event by Spring).

On top of that, Spring will inject the right bean based on your profile.

```
@Autowired
private MePage mePage; // AndroidMePage if android profile is active

@Autowired
private MePage mePage; // IOSMePage if ios profile is active
```

If your parent class is not abstract, you have to deal with multiple bean definitions as usual.

I think you have at least three options here.

**1) Declare one of the beans as `@Primary`**

```
@Component
public class MePage {}

@Profile("android")
@Component
@Primary
public class AndroidMePage extends MePage {}

@Profile("ios")
@Component
@Primary
public class IOSMePage extends MePage {}

@Autowired
private MePage mePage; // AndroidMePage if android profile is active

@Autowired
private MePage mePage; // IOSMePage if ios profile is active
```

**2) Autowire a `List` of beans**

```
@Component
public class MePage {}

@Profile("android")
@Component
public class AndroidMePage extends MePage {}

@Profile("ios")
@Component
public class IOSMePage extends MePage {}

@Autowired
private List<MePage> pages; // MePage and one of AndroidMePage or IOSMePage , based on active profile
```

**3) Add `@Qualifier` to your bean definitions and use that when autowiring**

```
@Component
@Qualifier("default")
public class MePage {}

@Profile("android")
@Component
@Qualifier("android")
public class AndroidMePage extends MePage {}

@Profile("ios")
@Component
@Qualifier("ios")
public class IOSMePage extends MePage {}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("default")
private MePage mePage; // MePage is injected, regardless of active profile

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ios")
private MePage mePage; // IOSMePage if ios profile is active

@Autowired
@Qualifier("android")
private MePage mePage; // AndroidMePage if android profile is active
```

Comment: I need to have parent class as abstract as there are some abstract methods which need to be defined in subclasses. Some non-abstract methods defined in the parent class itself.

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar You can let your parent class abstract, I was suggesting to remove the `@Component` at the top of it, leaving the class itself abstract.

Comment: So if I remove the `@Component` annotation from parent class, Spring will still automatically assign instance of subclass to the `@Autowired` parent class reference based on the profile?

Comment: If you have one and only one bean (i.e. spring managed component) for a given reference type when autowiring, Spring will pick the right bean and inject it for you.